# JLabel is being shown in wrong place

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with GUI. In my drawing simulator, I created a JLabel that show mouseclicks coordinates. I put it on southwest of my JFrame but after each click, in addition to its first place, mouse coordinates also appear on northwest of the JFrame. I didn't understand what ths problem is.The code is here.

```
    JLabel statusBar = new JLabel( "Mouse outside JPanel" );
    Container panel;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    panel = frame.getContentPane();
    panel.add(this);
    frame.setJMenuBar(jmb);
    frame.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(700,700);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

This is how I edit JLabel

```
    statusBar.setText( String.format( "Clicked at [%d, %d]", 
                        e.getX(), e.getY() ) );
```

The whole code can be longer thats why iam copying some important parts

```
          public class Tester extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {
          ....
```

This is how a draw a single line and I set the label's name here

```
      else if(lineci == true){
        if(mouseclicks == 0){
            l1.point1.x = e.getX();
            l1.point1.y = e.getY();
            statusBar.setText( String.format( "Clicked at [%d, %d]", 
                    e.getX(), e.getY() ) );
            mouseclicks++;
        }
        else if(mouseclicks == 1){
            l1.point2.x = e.getX();
            l1.point2.y = e.getY();
            statusBar.setText( String.format( "Clicked at [%d, %d]", 
                    e.getX(), e.getY() ) );
            mouseclicks = 0;
            int a = l1.point2.y - l1.point1.y;
            int b = l1.point1.x - l1.point2.x;
            int c = (l1.point2.x * l1.point1.y) - (l1.point1.x * l1.point2.y);
            l1.denklem[0] = a;
            l1.denklem[1] = b;
            l1.denklem[2] = c;
            array.add(l1);
            array3.add(l1);
            repaint();

        }
```

By the way, I 'm creating JLabel object outside the constructur of the class, just after creating class I mean.

Still same problem exists.

Comment: I dont understand your code.
what is base class?
What do you add to panel? `// panel.add(this);`
Send whole code

Comment: Please provide a fully self-contained example.

Comment: you add components to the contentPane(in your case is panel=frame.getContentPanel()), so you should add statusBar to the panel not frame. And also panel.add(this); should be something like this panel.add(this,BorderLayout.CENTER);

Comment: I agree with Mike above: if you need help here, your best bet is to provide a minimal self-contained compilable and runnable example, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). We don't want your whole program, just a small program that compiles, runs, demonstrates your problem but has no code unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Also, I have to wonder if 1) you're overriding paint or paintComponent, because if you are, the problem may be there, or 2) if you're using any transparent graphics in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
frame.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
```

Try

```
frame.getContentPane().add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this should help since as I understand things, `JFrame#add` is a convenience method that calls `getContentPane().add`.

Comment: @StanislavL still living in < Java5 :-)